# Ignore \addvspace at top of mdframed environment

Tags: spacing, conditionals, mdframed

In the MWE below, I include a `\addvspace{2.0ex}` before my figure. This looks fine, *except* if the figure is at the top of the `mdframe`. Is there a way to for the `\MyFigure` macro to decect if I am at the top of the frame so that `\addvspace{2.0ex}` is not added?

So, the first and third case work fine. It is the middle case which has additional spacing at the top (prior to the figure) that I would like to eliminate.

[image]

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\mdfdefinestyle{MyStyle}{%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=red!40,
    frametitlerule=true, 
    skipabove=0pt,
    skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
}

\newcommand*{\MyFigure}[1]{%
    \par
    \addvspace{2.0ex}% <--- This is the issue
    {\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=yellow!50] (0,0) rectangle (5,1) node [midway] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \par\addvspace{2.0ex}}
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
    style=MyStyle, 
    frametitle={Imagine in middle},
    ]
    Some text before.
    \MyFigure{Spacing above and below is fine}
    Some text following.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[
    style=MyStyle, 
    frametitle={Image on Top},
    ]
    \MyFigure{Spacing above is a problem}
    \noindent
    Some text following.
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[
    style=MyStyle, 
    frametitle={Image at End},
    ]
    Some text before.
    \MyFigure{Spacing above and below is fine}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \if@minipage  should be true at the start of the mdframed then addvspace won't add space

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I can't seem to get it to work using `\if@minipage`.

Comment: no I mean `\addvspace` already has an `\if@minipage` so it doesn't add space at top of a minipage, mdframed (or your code using it) should set `\@minipagetrue` at the start so spacing commands emulate top of page behaviour

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ahhh, yes adding `startcode={\@minipagetrue}`  to `\mdfdefinestyle` seems to do the job. Want to post an answer?

Comment: not just at present, if you have an answer tested feel free to post self answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Did further testing and I think the correct one to use is `startinnercode={}`, not `startcode={}` as mentioned above. Both seem to work in the test case. However, in my actual usage I am not geting quite the results I desire, as it seems that `addvspace{}` was already being suppressed at the top (without the `startinnercode={\@minipagetrue}`), but there is still some space.  So need futher investigation to see where it is coming from. Nonetheless, I am convinced that `startinnercode={}` works and is the correct thing to do for the given MWE.  Thanks you for your guidance.